# ANTLR 4 Error 50 - Mismatched Characer 'i' Expecting '{'

Tags: antlr4

ANTLR4 newbie here!

I'm trying to create my first ANTLR4 grammar - a tiny Oracle SQL*Loader - but don't seem to be able to get out of the starting gate!

When I run the grammar through recommended the alias antlr4, I get the following error message:

```
error(50): HQLLDR.g4::: syntax error: mismatched character 'i' expecting '{'
```

I thought the error was caused by using ANTLR4 keywords such as OPTIONS, so I changed the code to use OPTS instead, but the error still persists.

Here is the grammar:

```
grammar HQLLDR;

hqlldr: hqlhdr hqlbody ;

hqlhdr: LOAD DATA ;

hqlbody: hql_express hql_full ;

hql_express: infile_express ;

hql_full: options infile tbldefn fielddefn datalines ;

opts: OPTS '(' opt ( ',' opt )* ')' ;
opt: skipit | database | schema ;
skipit: SKIPIT '='  DIGIT+ ;
database: DATABASE '=' OBJNM ;
schema: SCHEMA '=' OBJNM ;

infile_express: INFILE filelist_express ;
filelist_express: '(' '"' file_express '"' ')' ;
file_express: TEXT ;

infile: INFILE (DATALINES | filelist)? ;
filelist: '(' '"' file '"' ( ',' '"' file '"' )* ')' ;
file: TEXT ;

tbldefn: (TRUNCATE | APPEND | CREATE) INTO TABLE tblnm ;
tblnm: OBJNM OBJDESC? ;

fielddefn: termdefn encdefn? fieldlist ;
termdefn: TERMINATED BY DELIMITER terminators ;
terminators: (TAB|SEMICOLON|COMMA|COLON|SPACE) ;
encdefn: ENCLOSED BY ENCLOSURE enclosures ;
enclosures: (DOUBLEQUOTE|APOSTROPHE) ;
fieldlist: '(' fieldname fielddesc? fielddatatype ( ',' fieldname fielddesc? fielddatatype )* ')' ;
fieldname: OBJNM ;
fielddesc:  OBJDESC? ;
fielddatatype: (BIGINT | INT | SMALLINT | TINYINT | TIMESTAMP | STRING | FLOAT | DOUBLE) ;

datalines: ROWTEXT '\r'? '\n' ;

ROWTEXT: ~[\n\r]+ ;
LETTER:   [a-zA-Z_] ;
DIGIT:   [0-9] ;
LOAD:   [Ll][Oo][Aa][Dd] ;
DATA:   [Dd][Aa][Tt][Aa] ;
OPTS:   [Oo][Pp][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn][Ss] ;
SKIPIT:   [Ss][Kk][Ii][Pp] ;
DATABASE:   [Dd][Aa][Tt][Aa][Bb][Aa][Ss][Ee] ;
SCHEMA:   [Ss][Cc][Hh][Ee][Mm][Aa] ;
INFILE:   [Ii][Nn][Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee] ;
DATALINES:   [Dd][Aa][Tt][Aa][Ll][Ii][Nn][Ee][Ss] ;
TRUNCATE:   [Tt][Rr][Uu][Nn][Cc][Aa][Tt][Ee] ;
APPEND:   [Aa][Pp][Pp][Ee][Nn][Dd] ;
CREATE:   [Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] ;
INTO:   [Ii][Nn][Tt][Oo] ;
TABLE:   [Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee] ;
FIELDS:   [Ff][Ii][Ee][Ll][Dd][Ss] ;
TERMINATED:   [Tt][Ee][Rr][Mm][Ii][Nn][Aa][Tt][Ee][Dd] ;
BY:   [Bb][Yy] ;
ENCLOSED:   [Ee][Nn][Cc][Ll][Oo][Ss][Ee][Dd] ;
OBJDESC:   '(' '"' .*? '"' ')' ;
OBJNM:   LETTER+ (LETTER | DIGIT)* ;
TEXT:   ~[,\n\r"']+ ;
TAB:   [Tt][Aa][Bb] ;
SEMICOLON:   [Ss][Ee][Mm][Ii][Cc][Oo][Ll][Oo][Nn] ;
COMMA:   [Cc][Oo][Mm][Mm][Aa] ;
COLON:   [Cc][Oo][Ll][Oo][Nn] ;
SPACE:   [Ss][Pp][Aa][Cc][Ee] ;
DELIMITER:   (TAB | SEMICOLON | COMMA | COLON | SPACE) ;
DOUBLEQUOTE:   [Dd][Oo][Uu][Bb][Ll][Ee][Qq][Uu][Oo][Tt][Ee] ;
APOSTROPHE:   [Aa][Pp][Oo][Ss][Tt][Rr][Oo][Pp][Hh][Ee] ;
ENCLOSURE:   (DOUBLEQUOTE | APOSTROPHE) ;
BIGINT:   [Bb][Ii][Gg][Ii][Nn][Tt] ;
INT:   [Ii][Nn][Tt] ;
SMALLINT:   [Ss][Mm][Aa][Ll][Ll][Ii][Nn][Tt] ;
TINYINT:   [Tt][Ii][Nn][Yy][Ii][Nn][Tt] ;
TIMESTAMP:   [Tt][Ii][Mm][Ee][Ss][Tt][Aa][Mm][Pp] ;
STRING:   [Ss][Tt][Rr][Ii][Nn][Gg] ;
FLOAT:   [Ff][Ll][Oo][Aa][Tt] ;
DOUBLE:   [Dd][Oo][Uu][Bb][Ll][Ee] ;
NL:   '\r'? '\n' ;
WS:   [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Oy!  Nevermind!  I forgot to change the rule "options" to "opts" as well as fix an issue with the fieldlist.  It compiled. :-)

Comment: No doubt that it compiled, but I highly doubt that the grammar does what you want it to do. Check my answer.

Comment: @BartKiers Agreed. I've probably bitten off more than I should have with my first ANTLR grammar.  Thanks again for your very helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR's lexer constructs tokens in the following way:

1. try to consume as much characters as possible for a single token (lexer rule)
2. if there are 2 or more lexer rules that match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

Given your lexer rule:

```
ROWTEXT: ~[\n\r]+ ;
```

and the input `"load data\n"`, it is (or should be) clear that only 2 tokens will be created:

```
ROWTEXT : 'load data'
NL      : '\n'
```

It doesn't matter if the parser is trying to match a `LOAD` token followed by a `DATA` token: the lexer operates independently from the parser.

You'll have to remove the `ROWTEXT` and try to construct it in the parser:

```
rowtext
 : ~NL+
 ;
```

Note that a `~` inside a parser rule negates tokens, not characters. So it means: "match one or more tokens other than NL".

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  As I said, I'm a newbie and still having trouble understanding the separation between the lexer and the parser.  You're comments have helped a lot, so thank you very much!!!!